# NullReferenceException when Double Clicked on ListBox entry

Tags: c#, wpf, nullreferenceexception, double-click, listboxitem

I've listBox in wpf application which contains two entries. I've written Double click event function for it.But when I click on any single entry, it shows me `NullReferenceException`. Exception is at line - `if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)`

I just want single entry on which I'll click. How should I proceed?

My Double click event is as follows:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Submit clicked Entry
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            if (!entryToPost.isSynced)
            {
                //Check if something is selected in selectedProjectItem For that item
                if (entryToPost.ProjectNameBinding == "Select Project")
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Project for the Entry");
                else
                    Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(entryToPost);
            }
            else
            {
                //Already synced.. Make a noise or something
                MessageBox.Show("Already Synced;TODO Play a Sound Instead");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Entry does not exist");
        }

     }
```

I assign eventhandler as,

```
InitializeComponent();
listBox1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(listBox1_MouseDoubleClick);
```

Comment: Can u show listBox1 markup please?

Comment: This is WPF? Looks like WinForms to me. Why not harvest the capabilities of WPF by utilizing databinding and operating on the bound collection instead?

Comment: Yes. I tried.It throws exception at very first line which I mentioned.

Comment: @Marius There's nothing that prevents programmers from using the code behind in WPF, but it's discouraged in favor of MVVM.

Comment: listBox1 markup-  <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Margin="0,131,0,59" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" ListBox.MouseDoubleClick="listBox1_MouseDoubleClick"/>

Comment: Try using the sender instead of the Listbox1 directly

Comment: @Marguth I tried but, still showing null reference exception.

Comment: Can you show us the templateSelector? 
In the example i built the listBox1 was never null in the eventhandler

Comment: templateSelector is shown above-<l:DayViewListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
              DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
              EditableDataTemplate="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}"/>

Comment: You should you SelectionChanged event.

Comment: And the Templates self pls, pls just simply provide everything so we can build this little part for ourself. So we can help u better.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line rather using listBox1 directly:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Submit clicked Entry
         if(sender is ListBox)
         {
            var listBoxRef = sender as ListBox;
            ...
            if (listBoxRef.SelectedItem != null)
            .....
            ....
      }
    }
```

Comment: I tried but, still showing null reference exception. I think, there is problem with SelectedItem because when I placed breakpoint and debug, it shows me null.

Answer (score 0):

I  have found something as follows . Give it a try. It will display the selected item text on double click. You can modify it as per your requirement.

```
void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     int index = this.listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
     if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
     }
}
```